# How to setup android sdk path for kotlin qodana?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying kotlin qodana for my sample android app but I am always getting error.
I am running this command.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/qodana/qodana-jvm-android.html

`docker run --rm -it -v /Users/vivart/Documents/develop/android/todo/:/data/project/ \ -p 8081:8080 jetbrains/qodana-jvm-android --show-report`

and I am getting this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The SDK path
'/Users/vivart/Library/Android/sdk'
does not belong to a directory.

IntelliJ IDEA will use this Android SDK instead:
'/opt/android-sdk'
and will modify the project's local.properties file.
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.TestDialog.lambda$static$0(TestDialog.java:8)
    at com.intellij.ui.messages.MessagesServiceImpl.showMessageDialog(MessagesServiceImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.Messages.showErrorDialog(Messages.java:661)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.Messages.showErrorDialog(Messages.java:688)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdk$0(SdkSync.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:214)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$200(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:196)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:794)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeAndWait$7(ApplicationImpl.java:451)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:134)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:189)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:885)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:754)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:441)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:825)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:440)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:794)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:486)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

2021/11/06 15:24:51 IDEA process exit code: 1
2021/11/06 15:24:51 Sync IDEA cache from: /data/project/.idea to: /data/cache/.idea
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing memory in Docker settings (Preferences | Resources | Advanced).
If that won't help, share logs again after you delete `local.properties` from the project and run Qodana.